# Does the Armor Class of a potion vial include the users Dexterity modifier?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, armor-class, potions

Page 478 of the core rulebook states:

> A typical potion or oil consists of 1 ounce of liquid held in a
>   ceramic or glass vial fitted with a tight stopper. The stoppered
>   container is usually no more than 1 inch wide and 2 inches high. The
>   vial has AC 13, 1 hit point, hardness 1, and a break DC of 12.

But is this true no matter who is holding it, regardless of any Dexterity modifier or Dodge bonus?

Answer (score 12):

Ugh, found my own answer on page 460.

**Yes, include dexterity modifier if being held by a creature.**  From that page, emphasis mine:

> General descriptions include notes on activation, random generation,
>   and other material. The AC, hardness, hit points, and break DC are
>   given for typical examples of some magic items. The AC assumes that
>   the item is unattended and includes a –5 penalty for the item’s
>   effective Dexterity of 0. **If a creature holds the item, use the
>   creature’s Dexterity modifier in place of the –5 penalty.**

Comment: Note that means that a potion vial held by someone with a 10 (+0) Dexterity is **18**, not 13.  That's a pretty huge difference.

Comment: And, oddly, that a stationary, unattended vial is *actually* AC 15 ("An object's Armor Class is equal to 10 + its size modifier... + its Dexterity modifier. An inanimate object has not only a Dexterity of 0 (−5 penalty to AC), [**but also an additional −2 penalty to its AC**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#TOC-Smashing-an-Object)"). *I don't know* when the typical unattended vial's AC would ever actually *be* 13.

Comment: @Heyicanchan Wouldn't that be AC 11? 10 + 8 size -5 dex -2 inanimate. It looks like whoever wrote up the potion vial missed the extra -2 penalty.

Comment: @Weaveworker89 Whatever it is, it for sure ain't 13. `:-)`